# How to reactively change css variables in svelte?

Tags: css-grid, svelte, css-variables

I want to display objects like this one inside a css grid:

```js
let data = {
    rows: [
      {
        id: "id",
        col1: "value1",
        col2: "value2",
      },
      {
        id: "id",
        col1: "value1",
        col2: "value2",
      },
    ],
  };
```

For this object the result should be this:

[image]

My problem is that the object can change and can contain a different number of columns each time.

Currently I am using:

```html
<script>
  export let data = {
    rows: [
      {
        id: "id",
        col1: "value1",
        col2: "value2",
      },
      {
        id: "id",
        col1: "value1",
        col2: "value2",
      },
    ],
  };

  function changeCols() {
    let r = document.querySelector(":root");
    r.style.setProperty("--columns", "4");
  }
</script>

<!-- A css grid to display sql data -->
<div class="grid">
  {#each data.rows as row}
    {#each Object.keys(row) as key}
      <div class="cell">{row[key]}</div>
    {/each}
  {/each}
</div>

<button on:click={changeCols}>make 4</button>

<style>
  :root {
    --columns: 3;
  }

  .grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  .cell {
    padding: 1rem;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
</style>
```

`changeCols()` throws an error saying that the style property doesn't exist. Why is this?

What would be a solution to this problem where I can easily change several css properties inside my javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable doesn't have to be set on the `:root` element, here it can be set on the grid element ([style:property](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-style-property)) and the number of columns automatically determined based on the data with a [reactive variable](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive)

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4c9077c7196e4c26b22ef3c2c0363994?version=3.58.0)

```
<script>
    export let data = {
        rows: [
            {
                id: "id",
                col1: "value1",
                col2: "value2",
            },
            {
                id: "id",
                col1: "value1",
                col2: "value2",
            },
        ],
    };

    $: cols = Object.entries(data.rows[0] ?? {}).length

    function changeCols() {
        data.rows.forEach(row => row['col3'] = 'value3') 
        data = data
    }

</script>

<div class="grid" style:--columns={cols}>
    {#each data.rows as row}
    {#each Object.keys(row) as key}
    <div class="cell">{row[key]}</div>
    {/each}
    {/each}
</div>

<button on:click={changeCols}>make 4</button>

<style>
    .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem;
    }

    .cell {
        padding: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
</style>
```